# Setting up Linux-C-DB2 environment

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, db2

I'm trying to set up an environment for learning: writing and testing simple C programs to perform DB2 database operations on an Ubuntu 18.04. system.

I installed DB2 with help of web tutorials and IBM pages, received database info from the installer, wrote simple programs in Gedit..

I compiled the simplest programs with Gnu C Compiler (gcc).

As soon as the compiler ran into the "EXEC SQL..." line it terminated and reported an error.

What's my next step in making this thing work?

Comment: It seems you're trying to use embedded SQL, not plain C code. For embedded SQL you need to use a special preprocessor program which turns your source into plain C which can then be compiled by `gcc`.

Comment: Didn't use preprocessor.. thanks

Comment: @Nikica please mark the answer that "works best for you", currently this topic stands as "not solved". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also learn from the IBM provided example embedded-SQL programs that are supplied (by default) with the Db2 on Linux.

These are in the samples subdirectory of the instance owner home directory (for example /home/db2inst1/samples/c.

In the samples directory there are subdirectories for many other programming languages to show how to use them with Db2.

The files containing embedded SQL for C programs have extension .sqc.

There is a long README, and some scripts that show you how to compile and build these programs, showing how to use the SQL preprocessor etc.

You can also see the samples online in the free Knowledge Center for Db2 , for example for V11.1 the URL to the C samples (and SQC samples) is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.samptop.doc/doc/r0007615.html).

Comment: The Db2 samples are also available here https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of nice starting point articles:

**[Db2] Compile a simple C application on Linux to verify environment**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-compile-simple-c-application-linux-verify-environment

It was written for RHEL 7.6 and CentOS 7.  But it should work with ubuntu.

```
... snip ...

select.sqc.
-----
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
#include <sqlenv.h>
#include <sqlutil.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  struct sqlca sqlca;
  EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    char dbAlias[15];
    char deptname[100];
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
  strcpy(dbAlias, argv[1]);
   :
... snip ...
```

```
... snip ...

db2 connect to $DBNAME
db2 PREP $CSOURCE.sqc BINDFILE
gcc -I$HOME/sqllib/include -c $CSOURCE.c
gcc -o $CSOURCE $CSOURCE.o -ldb2 -L$HOME/sqllib/lib
db2 bind $CSOURCE.bnd
... snip ...
```

It is recommended to review the article and follow steps.

Hope this helps.