# Environment COBOL, C, DB2 on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, db2, cobol

Corona sent me home and our company has strict rules and I don't have access to the network (IBM mainframe). I'm learning to program in COBOL, C, DB2 environment.
COBOL calls C, C works with DB2.

I'd like to continue working from home but I'm not an administrator.

Do you have any guidence, tips and tricks on how to set up an environment for this in Ubuntu?

So far I have a couple of editors, DB2 installation, gcc, gnu cobol...

Stuck on the embedded sql precompiler...

Comment: "Stuck on embedded sql precompiler" does not detail your problem. EDIT your question. Be specific.  That means show your commands (as text only, not graphics) and show the output, in your question (not in comments).

Answer (score 2):

gnucobol and gnucc both work with Db2-LUW on ubuntu linux.

You can build and run gnucobol programs that use embedded-SQL.

You can build and run gcc programs that use embedded-SQL via the preprocessor that comes with Db2-LUW, or which use the Db2 call level interface.

Each of these products has its own set of documentation pages online.
You have to spend time studying their respective documentation.

Stackoverflow is more suitable for specific programming questions.

You will get better answers if you learn to ask better questions that:

- show your code fragment as plain text (not an image).
- detail the environment and versions and tools that you use
- show the command(s) you run (as plain text)
- show the error output (as plain text) and mention the expected result

IBM's Db2-LUW has many example programs and simple build scripts (including for linux) that show how embedded SQL (used from C) can be used.

This was explained to you in January 2020, in answer to your [previous question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855377/setting-up-linux-c-db2-environment).